# Python: DRY vs explicit is better than implicit

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm constructing a API with django and the DRF. In this i make use of a custom ModelViewSet and MixIns. These implement the list(), update(), create(), and destroy() functions of my API. Now i have a whole battery of viewsets:

```
from kernel.api.viewsets.base implement CustomBaseViewSet

class MyModelViewSet1(CustomBaseViewSet):
      serializer_class = MyModel1Serializer 
      queryset =  MyModel1.objects.all()

class MyModelViewSet2(CustomBaseViewSet):
      serializer_class = MyModel2Serializer 
      queryset =  MyModel2.objects.all()

class MyModelViewSet3(CustomBaseViewSet):
      serializer_class = MyModel3Serializer 
      queryset =  MyModel3.objects.all()

 ... and so on ...
```

**Question 1**: I am now conflicted in the two Zen rules, should i explicitly bind the create, list, destoy and update methods (since explicit is better than implicit) or would that be considered a waste of breath...

```
class MyModel1ViewSet(CustomBaseViewSet)
      serializer_class = MyModel1Serializer 
      queryset =  MyModel1.objects.all()              

      def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().list(*args, **kwargs)

      def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().create(*args, **kwargs)
      ...
```

One thing i can think of in which the explicit method is more usefull than the DRY method, is that i can provide docstrings in the methods which show up as documentation in my DRF-api.

**Question 2:** Are there any other pros or cons between the DRY vs E>I-principles???

Comment: That's not explicit, that's redundant.

Comment: Yes, i would agree with that. But when i take into account the matter of the docstrings i can provide in the methods it _would_ make my API documentation more readable and specific for that viewset. Or is it still bad practice then?

Comment: If you find the individual docstrings useful, then personally I would say the duplication is ok, and I wouldn't worry too much about whether it's bad practice or not.

Comment: What I understand from your code is rather an overwrite of the method, without any functional update, only for the sake of the reader. There is no explicit biding per se, that takes place in the dispatch method. It is more verbose like this; one could argue that you may take the same info from the viewset declaration, based on inheritance scheme.

Comment: Yes. But my models inherit a base-viewset which implement basic things like field-level permissions, record locking etc. in the create() , update() and destroy() methods. Which i want to use for all my API endpoints. If i take the docstring from my BaseModelViewSet, it would be the same for all my API-endpoints.